# Regarding connectedness

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

If we define a set $G\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to be staircase-connected if two arbitrary points in $G$ can be connected by a staircase line consisting of horizontal and vertical lines contained in $G$, is it then true that if $G$ is open then:  G staircase-connected $\iff$ $G$ path connected?

Comment: Are your staircase lines allowed to switch direction, e.g. right-up-left-up-left-down, or can they only use one of (left,right) and one of (up,down)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. It's clear that staircase-connected $\implies$ path-connected. Now suppose that $G$ is path-connected; you want to prove that it is staircase-connected too. Fix a point $p\in G$ and let$$G^\star=\{z\in G\,|\,\text{there is a staircase path in $G$ from $p$ to }z\}.$$Using the fact that $G$ is open, it is easy to prove that $G^\star$ is both open and closed in $G$. Since $G^\star\neq\emptyset$, and since $G$ is connected, $G^\star=G$.

Comment: You should add to the definition of $G^*$: "a staircase path".

Comment: @MoisheCohen I've edited my answer. Thank you.